# Download multiple .txt files into .zip file with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Now in system it is possible to download .txt file generated from MySQL table row. I am trying to make it possible to download all .txt files in one zip file. Actually, I stuck on the point where I am not sure if my approach is possible.

```
 if (isset($_POST["ExportAll"])) {
    $query = $con->query("SELECT id, filename FROM thistable");

    $MultiArray = Array();
     while($result = $query->fetch_assoc()){
        $rowArray = Array();
        $rowArray[] = $result['id'];
        $rowArray[] = $result['filename'];
        $MultiArray[] = $rowArray;
    }

     foreach ($MultiArray as $arg) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM thistable WHERE id LIKE '" . $arg[0] . "';";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $arg[1] );
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        $output = fopen("php://output", "w");

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

            foreach(array_slice($row,2) as $line) {
                echo ("$line \r\n");
            }
         }
        fclose($output);
     }
 }
```

It is possible to put all `$output` values into some kind of `$zipArray = Array()` and then download it with `header("Content-type: application/zip");` 
 ?

Comment: Learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: Yes, it's possible to generate ZIP files in PHP. Surprisingly, it takes [a little more](http://php.net/zip) than just printing individual files to stdout and changing the `Content-Type` header.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález irony suits you very well. I mean, it is possible to add those printed files into one .zip file?

Comment: Sure. I've included a link to the exact PHP extension you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can download multiple text files as single zip file using php `ZipArchive` class. This is sample only you can try with your own scenario.

```
 $zipname = 'sample.zip';
 $zip = new ZipArchive;
 $zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
 $files_array = ["sample1", "sample2"]; // List of file names
 foreach ($files_array as $file) {
     $row = ["Line 1", "Line 2", "Line 3", "Line 5"]; // Assuming as your table row
     $filename = $file.".txt";
     $lines_to_add = "";
     foreach(array_slice($row, 2) as $line) {
         $lines_to_add .= $line."\r\n";
     }
     $zip->addFromString($filename, $lines_to_add);   // Adding lines to file
 }
 $zip->close();
 header('Content-Type: application/zip');
 header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipname);
 header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
 readfile($zipname);
 unlink($zipname); // Remove zip file if you don't want be in server
```

Comment: Yes, I am trying to use same approach, but I can't understand how to add all filenames values to `$files_array` , you could notice that in my case filenames are generated via `header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $arg[1] );`

Comment: @o.O - You are printing data to text file and then you need to download those printed files into zip file. Correct?

Comment: Elumalai, yes, exactly!

Comment: @o.O - Please see the updated answer that will surely helps you..! Execute on your local machine then see whether coming as you expected.

Comment: Many thanks for your help, solution works flawlessly!